# Truffle develop freezing. Trying to check variable values

Tags: truffle

truffle-config.js

```
module.exports = {
    compilers: {
      solc: {
        version: "^0.6.0"
      }
    },
    networks: {
        development: {
            host: "127.0.0.1",
            port: 8545,
            network_id: "*" // Any network
        },
        develop: {
          host: "127.0.0.1",
          port: 8545,
          network_id: "*" // Any network
      }
}
```

ganche-cli

```
Listening on 127.0.0.1:8545
```

Yet when I run

```
$ truffle develop
```

Truffle develop freezes and won't load anything. How do I run an instance of my contract so that I can see what it's doing?

I tried running tests but I can't see any return values. I can only use assert to verify if variables are what I want them to be.

How can I make what's happening less opaque so I can make sure everything is working how it should?

Comment: Try renaming/deleting build/ directory. I've never experienced truffle freezing. Which node version are you using? (I'm using 10 without issues, 12 fails to install some dependency of web3) Is it a VM or a real machine? (my is windows 10 with 8Gb).

Comment: Hey thank you! I figured it out :) It’s just taking me a sec to figure out how all these pieces fit together